# Unable to send token from AngularJS to Laravel API

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

This is how I am handling the process of sendig the `csrf_token()`.

In the `<head>` section I added the token as a constant.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'productController', 'productService'])
        .constant("CSRF_TOKEN", '<?= csrf_token() ?>');
</script>
```

In the `productService` when I send post data, I include the following:

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'X-XSRF-TOKEN': CSRF_TOKEN}
```

Then I receive from Laravel the error:

```
DecryptException: invalid data
```

If I remove `X-XSRF-TOKEN` from `headers:` above, then I receive the `TokenMismatchException`.

As suggested from another post, I encrypted the `csrf_token()`, since Laravel is expecting the token to be encrypted, but even then I still receive `DecryptException: invalid data`.

Comment: Use your browser's *Network* console to confirm the value sent in the request. I'd also use `json_encode()` to print the token in case it contains any unsafe characters (like single-quote), ie `.constant('CSRF_TOKEN', <?= json_encode(csrf_token()) ?>)`

Comment: @Phil Yes it is. I appreciate the tip of the Network console, I was always using the raw console only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `X-XSRF-TOKEN` to `X-CSRF-TOKEN` solved the problem.

When testing, I had to destroy the cookie and restart the browser for the token to kick in.

Comment: I am not using exactly the same method of constant but I use the same function and store the token in the meta tag. `<meta name="csrf-token" ng-init='csrf_token = <?php echo csrf_token(); ?>'>` But I get `token mismatch` if I use `CSRF` and `cannot decrypt` error if using `XSRF`! I am using laravel 5.And I face this on server on local angular default generates a token with each request

Comment: I have added a question here,if you could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29863483/unable-to-decryt-csrf-xsrf-token-in-laravel-sent-through-angular

Answer (score 0):

change `XSRF` to `CSRF` and restart your browser.