# Unable to decrypt CSRF/XSRF token in Laravel sent through Angular

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, csrf

I am using the angularavel setup for my app. On my local setup i do not need to explicitly send the `XSRF-TOKEN` with the angular http request. And it works fine with laravel. I uploaded the same setup on the server and tried to login using my form and laravel throws a `token mismatch` error. Hence I checked the request payload in dev tools and found there is no XSRF-TOKEN header in the request,like I see on my local. I believe angular generates one by default and send it with every http request,but not sure why is it failing here.

I added the csrf token in angular based on this tutorial [here](http://angularjs4u.com/security/inject-laravel-4-csrf-token-angularjs/) using the meta tag method. my meta is
`<meta name="csrf-token" content='<?php echo json_encode(csrf_token()); ?>'> // Also tried without encoding`
In my .config I have

`$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');`
If I use `X-XSRF-TOKEN` I get DecryptException in Encrypter.php line 142:Invalid data.
If I use `X-CSRF-TOKEN` I get Token Mismatch error.
 My request shows the token in the header(added below).

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:68
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Cookie:PHPSESSID=ySsuvCYycB-9IfZZ29kSF1
Host:demo.abc.com
Origin:http://demo.abc.com
Referer:http://demo.abc.com/hexa/public/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36 FirePHP/4Chrome
X-FirePHP-Version:0.0.6
X-Wf-Max-Combined-Size:261120
X-XSRF-TOKEN:InhRWmVjcUxZNWVMRWlrWmFXR09vbGdZT1M2Z284c0NqV2x2RWxaN0Mi  -->token
```

Where am I commiting mistake? Also the defult token from angular seems to be integrated and a vry large string.whereas the one genrated by function is a small string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me, I'll show you the relevant snippets.

In my template I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">myApp.constant("CSRF_TOKEN", '<?= csrf_token() ?>');</script>
```

And I have a factory such as:

```
.factory('Product', function($http, CSRF_TOKEN) {    
    return {
        // store a product
        save : function(productData) {            
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost/angularjs/public/api/products',
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': CSRF_TOKEN},
                data: productData
            });
        },
    }
});
```

This is all I needed to do to stop receiving csrf token related errors.

Comment: So you add the `headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': CSRF_TOKEN},` with every http request explicitly? How do you decrypt it on server side?You used laravel or some other language/technology to do it?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5. I'll use `headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': CSRF_TOKEN}` when doing a post request. This is what the csrf_token is for in Laravel.

Comment: $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'); wouldn't this do the same? I just figured out my compiled.php in the vendor folder was not generated which was probably causing the issue! I will update once I test it.

Answer (score 0):

that lines in module angular work for me....

```
in module angularjs
 $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content');
     $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content');
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;

i
```